# Colspan in table cell (td) shifts cells

Tags: html, xslt, html-table

I am altering a table using XSLT to host information from a device. Not a big problem except I need to recreate a screen with elements on it. For Example:

```
-----------
|          |
|  X       |
|          |
|          |
|     XXX  |
|     XXX  |
|          |
------------
```

This screen has for example 2 elements. one with a size of 1x1 (not a problem) but when with a size of 3x2. When i change this cells rowspan or colspan, the cells shift and will not disappear into the colspan.

So this is what really happens:

```
-----------
|          |
|  X       |
|          |
|          |
|     XXX    |
|     XXX    |
|          |
------   --|
      ---
```

an exmaple in code would like:

```
<TABLE border="1">
    <TBODY>
        <TR style="height: 10px;">
            <TD BGCOLOR="#CDB599">&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD COLSPAN="2" BGCOLOR="#9CC5C9">&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD BGCOLOR="#CDB599">&nbsp;</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR style="height: 10px;">
            <TD BGCOLOR="#D5544F">&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD BGCOLOR="#CDB599">&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD BGCOLOR="#CDB599">&nbsp;</TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ju9dd/12/

Anyone got any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Edited post with some code and a jsfiddle

Comment: The reason your table is broken is because the number of columns don't match, your first row has four columns, your second has three.  Rule one of tables - match the number of cells in each row

Answer (score 0):

Colspan does not make the adjacent cell magically dissappear.  You need to leave it out.

Proper code:

```
<TABLE border="1">
    <TBODY>
        <TR style="height: 10px;">
            <TD BGCOLOR="#CDB599">&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD COLSPAN="2" BGCOLOR="#9CC5C9">&nbsp;</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR style="height: 10px;">
            <TD BGCOLOR="#D5544F">&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD BGCOLOR="#CDB599">&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD BGCOLOR="#CDB599">&nbsp;</TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: I know, but I create this table dynamically. So I have a table with al td's and tr's and I want to dynamically remove the td's and tr's which will be overwritten by the element. http://jsfiddle.net/9PxVK/3/